# Less or more command on Solaris for paginating output

Tags: solaris, command-line-interface, solaris-11

When I type "ifconfig | more" or "ifconfig | less" the output isn't paginated on Solaris (I'm used to Linux and FreeBSD).  Is there a way to do this on Solaris 11?

Answer (score 5):

The reason is, unlike Linux, `ifconfig` without options isn't a valid command under Solaris. The equivalent command would be `ifconfig -a`.
If you run it without options, `ifconfig` displays a help message on its standard error stream.

To have it paginated, simply use:

```
ifconfig 2>&1 | less
```

By the way, `ifconfig` is somewhat obsolete under Solaris 11. I would recommended to use the more powerful [ipadm](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19963-01/html/821-1462/ipadm-1m.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to properly configure your terminal type, specially if SSHing from a linux box:

export TERM=vt100

Comment: Thanks, it didn't seem to work.  I'm sshing from PuTTY on Win7 box.